# Multilevel Complex Nested Json Using Spark SQL

Tags: json, apache-spark-sql

I have a specific requirement to convert some related tables data in nested json like below by using Spark SQL. I have achieved it with Scala but not getting it resolved in Spark SQL.

{
   "REPORTING_CARRIER":"9E",
   "DISTANCE":"3132",
   "ORIGIN_STATE_NM":"Pennsylvania",
   "QUARTER":"2",
   "YEAR":"2017",
   "ITIN_GEO_TYPE":"2",
   "BULK_FARE":"0",
   "ORIGIN":"ABE",
   "ORIGIN_AIRPORT_ID":"10135",
   "ITIN_FARE":"787",
   "ORIGIN_CITY_MARKET_ID":"30135",
   "ROUNDTRIP":"1",
   "Market":[
      {
         "MKT_DISTANCE":"1566",
         "MKT_BULK_FARE":"0",
         "MKT_NO_OF_CPNS":"2",
         "MKT_DEST_STATE_NM":"Texas",
         "MKT_OP_CARR_GRP":"9E:DL",
         "MKT_TK_CARR_GRP":"DL:DL",
         "MKT_MILES_FLOWN":"1566",
         "MKT_AIRPORT_GROUP":"ABE:ATL:SAT",
         "MKT_FARE_AMT":"393.5",
         "MKT_ORIG_STATE_NM":"Pennsylvania",
         "MKT_DEST_ARPT_CITY_NM":"33214",
         "MKT_RPTG_CARR_NM":"9E",
         "MKT_DEST":"SAT",
         "MKT_DEST_CNTRY":"US",
         "MKT_ORIG_CNTRY":"US",
         "Coupon":[
            {
               "CPN_STATE_NM":"Georgia",
               "CPN_DEST":"ATL",
               "CPN_TKT_CARR_NM":"DL",
               "TRIP_BREAK":"",
               "CPN_MKT_ORIG_ARPT_NM":"10135",
               "CLASS_OF_SVC":"X",
               "CPN_TKT_NBR":"2017245",
               "CPN_DEST_CITY_MKT_NM":"30397",
               "CPN_DISTANCE":"692",
               "SEQ_NUM":"1",
               "ITIN_GEO_TYPE":"2",
               "CPN_RPTG_CARR_NM":"9E",
               "COUPON_GEO_TYPE":"2",
               "CPN_ORIG_STATE_NM":"Pennsylvania",
               "CPN_OPERG_CARR_NM":"9E",
               "CPN_ORIG":"ABE",
               "CPN_PASSENGERS":"1",
               "COUPON_TYPE":"A",
               "CPN_DEST_ARPT_NM":"10397",
               "CPN_MKT_ORIG_CITY_NM":"30135",
               "CPN_DEST_CNTRY":"US",
               "CPN_MKT_ID":"201724501",
               "CPN_ORIG_CNTRY":"US"
            },
            {
               "CPN_STATE_NM":"Texas",
               "CPN_DEST":"SAT",
               "CPN_TKT_CARR_NM":"DL",
               "TRIP_BREAK":"X",
               "CPN_MKT_ORIG_ARPT_NM":"10397",
               "CLASS_OF_SVC":"X",
               "CPN_TKT_NBR":"2017245",
               "CPN_DEST_CITY_MKT_NM":"33214",
               "CPN_DISTANCE":"874",
               "SEQ_NUM":"2",
               "ITIN_GEO_TYPE":"2",
               "CPN_RPTG_CARR_NM":"9E",
               "COUPON_GEO_TYPE":"2",
               "CPN_ORIG_STATE_NM":"Georgia",
               "CPN_OPERG_CARR_NM":"DL",
               "CPN_ORIG":"ATL",
               "CPN_PASSENGERS":"1",
               "COUPON_TYPE":"A",
               "CPN_DEST_ARPT_NM":"14683",
               "CPN_MKT_ORIG_CITY_NM":"30397",
               "CPN_DEST_CNTRY":"US",
               "CPN_MKT_ID":"201724501",
               "CPN_ORIG_CNTRY":"US"
            }
         ],
         "MKT_ITIN_ID":"2017245",
         "MKT_OPERG_CARR_NM":"99",
         "MKT_DEST_ARPT_NM":"14683",
         "MKT_ORIG_ARPT_NM":"ABE",
         "MKT_ITIN_GEO_TYPE":"2",
         "MKT_PASSENGERS":"1",
         "MKT_ID":"201724501",
         "MKT_TKT_CARR_NM":"DL"
      },
      {
         "MKT_DISTANCE":"1566",
         "MKT_BULK_FARE":"0",
         "MKT_NO_OF_CPNS":"2",
         "MKT_DEST_STATE_NM":"Pennsylvania",
         "MKT_OP_CARR_GRP":"DL:DL",
         "MKT_TK_CARR_GRP":"DL:DL",
         "MKT_MILES_FLOWN":"1566",
         "MKT_AIRPORT_GROUP":"SAT:ATL:ABE",
         "MKT_FARE_AMT":"393.5",
         "MKT_ORIG_STATE_NM":"Texas",
         "MKT_DEST_ARPT_CITY_NM":"30135",
         "MKT_RPTG_CARR_NM":"9E",
         "MKT_DEST":"ABE",
         "MKT_DEST_CNTRY":"US",
         "MKT_ORIG_CNTRY":"US",
         "Coupon":[
            {
               "CPN_STATE_NM":"Georgia",
               "CPN_DEST":"ATL",
               "CPN_TKT_CARR_NM":"DL",
               "TRIP_BREAK":"",
               "CPN_MKT_ORIG_ARPT_NM":"14683",
               "CLASS_OF_SVC":"X",
               "CPN_TKT_NBR":"2017245",
               "CPN_DEST_CITY_MKT_NM":"30397",
               "CPN_DISTANCE":"874",
               "SEQ_NUM":"3",
               "ITIN_GEO_TYPE":"2",
               "CPN_RPTG_CARR_NM":"9E",
               "COUPON_GEO_TYPE":"2",
               "CPN_ORIG_STATE_NM":"Texas",
               "CPN_OPERG_CARR_NM":"DL",
               "CPN_ORIG":"SAT",
               "CPN_PASSENGERS":"1",
               "COUPON_TYPE":"A",
               "CPN_DEST_ARPT_NM":"10397",
               "CPN_MKT_ORIG_CITY_NM":"33214",
               "CPN_DEST_CNTRY":"US",
               "CPN_MKT_ID":"201724503",
               "CPN_ORIG_CNTRY":"US"
            },
            {
               "CPN_STATE_NM":"Pennsylvania",
               "CPN_DEST":"ABE",
               "CPN_TKT_CARR_NM":"DL",
               "TRIP_BREAK":"X",
               "CPN_MKT_ORIG_ARPT_NM":"10397",
               "CLASS_OF_SVC":"X",
               "CPN_TKT_NBR":"2017245",
               "CPN_DEST_CITY_MKT_NM":"30135",
               "CPN_DISTANCE":"692",
               "SEQ_NUM":"4",
               "ITIN_GEO_TYPE":"2",
               "CPN_RPTG_CARR_NM":"9E",
               "COUPON_GEO_TYPE":"2",
               "CPN_ORIG_STATE_NM":"Georgia",
               "CPN_OPERG_CARR_NM":"DL",
               "CPN_ORIG":"ATL",
               "CPN_PASSENGERS":"1",
               "COUPON_TYPE":"A",
               "CPN_DEST_ARPT_NM":"10135",
               "CPN_MKT_ORIG_CITY_NM":"30397",
               "CPN_DEST_CNTRY":"US",
               "CPN_MKT_ID":"201724503",
               "CPN_ORIG_CNTRY":"US"
            }
         ],
         "MKT_ITIN_ID":"2017245",
         "MKT_OPERG_CARR_NM":"DL",
         "MKT_DEST_ARPT_NM":"10135",
         "MKT_ORIG_ARPT_NM":"SAT",
         "MKT_ITIN_GEO_TYPE":"2",
         "MKT_PASSENGERS":"1",
         "MKT_ID":"201724503",
         "MKT_TKT_CARR_NM":"DL"
      }
   ],
   "NO_OF_CPNS":"4",
   "ORIGIN_COUNTRY":"US",
   "ITIN_ID":"2017245",
   "PASSENGERS":"1",
   "MILES_FLOWN":"3132"
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [from_json()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) helper function within the select() Dataset API call, to extract or decode data's attributes and values from a JSON string into a DataFrame as columns, dictated by a schema.

example, given the following json `{ "reporting_carrier": "A", "market": { "value": 10 } }`, stored in the rawJsonDf

```
case class MarketData (reporting_carrier: String, market_json: String)

val jsonSchema = new StructType()
  .add("value", LongType)

rawJsonDf
  .toDf("reporting_carrier","market")
  .as[MarketData]

rawJsonDf
  .select(from_json($"market_json", jsonSchema) as "market")
  .filter($"market.value" > 5)
```

see [this great tutorial by databricks for more info](https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/complex-nested-structured.html).